# Use a class customization to resolve this conflict in java WSIMPORT

Tags: soap, wsdl2java, wsimport

I have an wsdl like below:

```
<xs:element name="getlocationlist">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="auth" type="tns:AuthDTO"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="getlocationlist" 
type="tns:getlocationlist"/>
</xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="getlocationlist">
 <xs:sequence>
 <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ExtensionData" 
  type="tns:ExtensionDataObject"/>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="getlocationlistResponse">
<xs:complexType>
 <xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="getlocationlistResult">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
 <xs:any/>
 </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
 </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

As you see there are some duplicate element "getlocationlist", wsimport is not able to generate the stub and recommending to use a class customization. Is there anyone outthere know How to use class customization or extra binding to handle that. Thanks and appreciation in andvance.Please ask if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue. Here is my solution:

1. Download apache cxf binary from http://cxf.apache.org/download.html
2. Extract it and add it to your path. In MAC, update your bash_profile
3. Run the command below:

`wsdl2java -client -p your_package_name -autoNameResolution https://gateway.abc.com/something.svc?wsdl`